# Scala: type mismatch in function composition, found (Int, Int) => Seq[Int] require ? => Seq[Int]

Tags: scala, type-systems, function-composition

I'm trying to compose 2 functions in a script and getting a type mismatch I can not solve.
Here is the sample code:

```scala
def generate(start: Int, end: Int): Seq[Int] = (start until end).toSeq
def restrain(seq: Seq[Int]) = seq.dropWhile(_ < 20).takeWhile(_ < 60)

val com: (Int, Int) => Seq[Int] = (restrain _ compose generate)
```

By loading this in the REPL with:

```scala
:load test.sc
```

I get the following error:

```
       val com: (Int, Int) => Seq[Int] = (restrain _ compose generate)
                                                             ^
test.sc:1: error: type mismatch;
        found   : (Int, Int) => Seq[Int]
        required: ? => Seq[Int]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314340/2707792) (even though it answers a different question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types `Function2[Int, Int, Seq[Int]]` and `Function1[(Int, Int), Seq[Int]]` are not the same. The `(generate _)` produces the former, whereas for this composition, you need the latter. Try:

```
restrain _ compose (generate _).tupled
```